# What is the best practice for the multiple use of the same link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to rationalize a website, and I have many links on it to the same document, so I want to create a JavaScript that return the URL of this document. This way, i could update the document and only have to change the URL in the function, not in all the occurrences of the link (it's a professional and internal website, with many links to official documents, that get updated often, out of my control, and each time i get to update links, i realize a while after that i forgot some, even by searching in all html files. the site is messy, was poorly written by many people, and that's why i'm trying to simplify)

My first idea was to use `<A href="javascript:F_link_pdf()">link</A>`, but everyone says it's a bad practice. i still don't see why, and I don't like to use the `onclick` as it doesn't work with middle click, and i want to let users decide how they open the doc.

Also, I want to use `<A href="javascript:F_link_pdf()#page=39">link</A>` to redirect to a specific page.

on top of this, what i tried so far is not working like I intend, so i would need some help, whether to come up with a better solution, or to make this work!

here is my js, with different versions:

```
function F_link_PDF() {
    // i was pretty sure this would work
    return "http://www.example.com/presentation.pdf" ;
}
function F_link_PDF_2() {
    document.write("http://www.example.com/presentation.pdf");
}
function F_link_PDF_3() {
    // i don't like this solution, as it doesn't open as user intended to
    location.href = "http://www.example.com/presentation.pdf" ;
}
```

this example is for a pdf document, but i could also need this for html, doc, ppt...
and finally, i started with js because i'm used to, but I could also use other languages, php, asp, if someone says it's a better option

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `.htaccess` & `mod_rewrite` and rewrite the URL? You could also use `FallbackResource` to point to a php file that would have additional logic in it (then pass off a `header('Location: http://new/resource/file.ext');`)

Comment: Doing it on the client side, with javascript, is probably "bad practice" because a) it's browser dependent, some users may not have javascript enabled and for something as simple as a link there's no reason to require it b) it messes with how Google sees the link, so they may not crawl it. Using something like PHP where you could abstract it away on the server side and client side sees no difference would probably be fine.

Comment: @TZHX: _"it's a professional and internal website"_ -- Something tells me SEO isn't an issue. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie Sorry... I did skip a bit on the wall of text. But "best practice" on web / html is going to focus on the general case so I think my reasons for why people would label that "bad practice" are still fair.

Comment: Your question is tagged PHP, so why not use it?

Comment: Because, even though i know some basics on php, and i feel it could be a good solution (hence the tag), i don't know how to do so! and no, SEO is not an issue for me, google should not crawl in there :) but I prefer to learn this, so thank you @TZHX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *hack* way: Go about using JavaScript, however you run into potential issues with browsers not running it.

The *better* way: Use `mod_rewrite` / `.htaccess` to redirect previous (expired) requests to the new location of the resource. You could also use `FallbackResource` and provide a .php file that could provide the new resource based on criteria (you now have the power of PHP to decide where the `Location` header should go).

The *best* way<sup>1</sup>: Place those document references in a database table somewhere and reference them in the page using the table's current value. This creates a single place of "truth" and allows you to update the site from a global perspective. You could also, at a later date, provide search, tag, display a list, etc.

<sup>1</sup> *Not implying it's the abosolute best, but it is certainly a better way than updating hard-coded references.*

Comment: I like your best way, but how would you read the table? (i mean, i have some ideas, but i'm still on the best practice perspective here!)

Comment: Reference it by file id, by name (but has to be unique) or use a combined key (department and file number). Its up top you on how to best organize the information.

Comment: I mean, what technology would you use to read that table? that's also what I had in mind, a table to list the most recurrent links, but I don't know how to put that link into the href? so far my pages where quite simple, and I'm trying to learn more powerful techniques

Comment: PHP , MYSQL and PDO. and probably build a file.php and pass it a file id.

Comment: @Rafiki: https://gist.github.com/bchristie/762ee31ca398c07c5295 Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A server side programming language like php is a better option.

Here's example code that helps:

```
<?php
$link="http://www.example.com/files/document.pdf";
if ($_GET['PAGE'] == "downloads")
    {
      ?>
      This is a download page where you can download our flyer.
      <?php
      echo "<a href=\"".$link."\">Download PDF</a>";
    }

if ($_GET['PAGE'] == "specials")
    {
      ?>
      This is our store specials page. check them out. a link to the flyer is below.
      <?php
      echo "<a href=\"".$link."\">Download PDF</a>";
    }
?>
```

The code isn't 100% perfect since some text needs adjusting but what it does is it takes a parameter PAGE and sees that it is "downloads" or "specials" and if it is, it loads the appropriate page and adds the link to the download file. If you try both pages, the link to the download is exactly the same.

If the above php script is saved as index.php, then you can call each page with:

```
index.php?PAGE=specials   for the specials page
index.php?PAGE=downloads  for the download page
```

Once that works, then you can add another "if" section for another page to create but the most important line in each section is the last line of...

```
echo "<a href=\"".$link."\">Download PDF</a>";
```

...because it's taking a variable thats usable in every case in the script.

An advantage with using server side method is that people can view the site even with javascript disabled.

Comment: `index.php?PAGE=specials`is what you write in the HTML? does it have to be converted to a PHP page? I'm familiar with the concept of PHP but never actually used it. thanks!

Comment: That is a link. You can use `<a href="index.php?PAGE=specials">Visit our Specials page</a>` on any page. Then the link loads the specials page with a link to the common PDF file.